# How can max-width CSS media query accommodate zoom?

Tags: html, css, zooming

I'm using a CSS Media Query to adjust the look of my page if it is very narrow.  In my simplified example, if the page is less than 300px wide, I'll make the background blue.

```
@media all and (max-width: 300px) {
    body{ background-color:blue;}
}
```

I recently discovered that if the user zooms (Ctrl+Scrollwheel or on Chrome Wrench>Zoom) that the max-width will still kick in at 300 actual pixels, not 300 zoomed pixels.  This can break sites with more sophisticated layouts.  Is there any way for the max-width media query to handle users with zoomed browsers?

Comment: Browsers should implement this (like firefox already does). I don't think there is any way of doing this yourself, except using JS. Just use flexible layouts. Some thinks would become a bit more cramped than you'd like, but as long as the site is still usable...

Comment: After a little experimentation: using "max-width:10em" works when you zoom. HOWEVER this does not work in chrome. Firefox works fine (haven't tested in other browsers) but chrome seams to bug out.Ill see if I can figure out what to do about chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I've experimented around and it seems that you can use media queries for a zoom, however in a Webkit browser you must define the viewport.

Comment: Sure, check [my site](http://ilxr.co) for example. As you zoom on the page, the media queries kick in but still respect the browser due to defining the viewport and also using percentage widths.